# PLSQL check if a variable only contains Char(10)s and no other value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Hi I'm trying to compare two VARCHAR2 variables - `new_value`, `old_value`. I'm using `Replace()` to check the if there are common values and removing them from the `new_value`. The problem arises when:

```
old value = Test 1
            Test 2

new_value = Test 1
            Test 2
            Char(10)
```

In this case the `Replace()` will remove all the values except the new line. I need way to check if only new line characters and/or spaces are there in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ASCII` function to get the `ASCII` value of remaining data after replace and then easily check if it is space or newline as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT ASCII(REPLACE(N,O)) FROM
  2  (SELECT
  3      'Test 1
  4       Test 2' AS O,
  5      'Test 1
  6       Test 2'
  7       || CHR(10) AS N
  8  FROM
  9      DUAL);

ASCII(REPLACE(N,O))
-------------------
                 10 -- it means, it is new line

SQL>
```